# AZURE AD:How to get authorization code without redirection?

Tags: java, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to write java code which will go to login.microsoftonline.com
to obtain authorization code and store it in String variable without any redirection ?

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
>   client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e &response_type=code
>   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A%12345 &response_mode=query
>   &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F &state=12345

Best Regards

Comment: no. Authorization Code imposes user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

No. Because authorization code can only be obtained via user interaction. You may want to read the [Authorization Code Grant Flow in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) to fully understand this flow.

Further more, the [Authentication Basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) is really good starting resource.